# Excel Attendance Sheet, Adding hours on master sheet using a separate sheet/page

Tags: excel

So I have a master member list in excel containing all member ID numbers of a club (Around 200). These ID numbers are in column A. Column H-onwards are different meeting dates. If the member went to that meeting, I put in the number of minutes they went to their cell. This master sheet sums the number of minutes a member went to meetings.

This takes forever.

I have another sheet containing the list of member IDs (Around 50) of people who went to a specific meeting. They all went for 40 minutes. How can I add the 40 minutes to each corresponding person in the master sheet, in lets say, column K?

Comment: is there any time already mentioned in the column k? if so you want to add 40 minutes right?

Comment: Column K is empty. Mini sheet just contains the IDs of the members who came to the meeting. I want to match their IDs with the ones in the Master Sheet and add 40 minutes in the master sheet in column K to only the ones who came to the meeting.

Comment: can you share screenshots or images of your excel?

Comment: If I am to understand your question, you want to a  sheet (say Sheet2) of information to lookup a corresponding user in the first sheet (say Sheet1), and then find the last available column for that user and add the values from Sheet2 into Sheet1?

Comment: Basically, yes. @Jhecht

Comment: @AmbrishPathak http://imgur.com/a/0k5AH

Comment: I can give you basics but realistically since I don't have the specific information that you do it's really a toss up if it will work correctly in your file.

Comment: @Jhecht Yes please!

Comment: quick question before I do: are you trying to use Excel's VBA for this?

Comment: I have no idea what VBAs are (lol sorry), I just want something as simple as possible.

Comment: Hmm, that does complicate things a twitch.